# CSS menu - stop child items from changing parent width

Tags: css, sass

I have a two-level CSS menu. Both levels should be displayed horizontally.

I have this pretty much set up, but there are a few issues I can't figure out.

[image: css menu]

1) Can I stop the "Projects" link from gaining the same width as the below elements? ("Live" and "Work" combined)

2) Can I left-align "Live" and "Work" below "Projects" without messing up the above structure?

This is the end result I want to achieve:

[image: css menu result]

3) Is this possible using inline-block elements instead of floats? Should I use those instead? Knowing the menu should be positioned absolute at the top right of the page.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v23xejtj

```css
.menu-block--main      { position: absolute; top: 5%; right: 5%;

  // level 1
  ul                   { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;
    li                 { float: left; background-color: green; }
    li a               { display: block; color: #000; text-align: center; 
      padding: 14px 16px; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; }
    li a:hover         { background-color: red; }
  }

  // level 2
  ul li ul             { 
    li                 { float: left; }
  }

}
```

```html
<nav class="menu-block--main">
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a>Projects</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="menu-item"><a>Live</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a>Work</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a>Activities</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a>Team</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a>Blog</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to set submenu absolute as well, so main menu item won't change it size. Also you can delete float:left, use display: inline-block, vertical-align:top and text-align: left. You should also set background to the whole menu and submenu.

```
 .menu-block--main {
     background: #008000;
 }

.menu-block--main ul{
    text-align: left;
}

.menu-block--main ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.menu-block--main ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: #008000;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
}
```

Hope I helped ;)

Comment: Shouldn't the `.menu-block--main ul li` have `position: relative;` so the submenu will be under it's parent?

Comment: It can be relative or absolute. Works both ways. It just can't be static.

Comment: Sorry, I didin't notice it's about "li". Yeah, li should be relative. Sorry about that ;)

Comment: Had to add the position-relative to the .menu-block--main ul, everything else works great. Thx!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you mean to make sub menu, i think like this:

```
.menu-block--main{
    ul.main-menu{
      background: #444;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;

      li{
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        line-height: 40px;
        text-align: left;

        a{
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #fff;
          display: block;
          padding-left: 15px;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
          transition: .3s background-color;
          &:hover{
            background-color: #005f5f;
          }
          &:active{
            background-color: #aaa;
            color: #444;
            cursor: default;
          }
        }
      }
      li{
        font-size: .8em;
      }
    }
}
```

... hopefully can help you